# Angular 4 Error loading component

Tags: angular, import, components

I was hoping to use the [ng4-material-dropdown](https://github.com/EricSites/ng4-material-dropdown) and installed the package as instruced by calling `npm install ng4-material-dropdown --save` from my project's root folder. While I can confirm this folder exists inside `/node-components`, importing it in my `app.module.ts` throws an error.

Import
`import { Ng4DropdownModule } from 'ng4-material-dropdown';`

Error

> Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
>   http://localhost:3000/ng4-material-dropdown
>     patchProperty/desc.set/wrapFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1055:30
>     ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:17
>     Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:28
>     ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:486:28
>         Error loading http://localhost:3000/ng4-material-dropdown as
>   "ng4-material-dropdown" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
>   Stack trace: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
>   http://localhost:3000/ng4-material-dropdown
>     patchProperty/desc.set/wrapFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1055:30
>     ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:17
>     Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:28
>     ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:486:28
>         Error loading http://localhost:3000/ng4-material-dropdown as
>   "ng4-material-dropdown" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js

This is probably a very rooky mistake, but I can't for the life of me figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

If you generated the app with the angular cli, you should have an angular.cli.json. It has a list of external vender scripts to package in. Its nested in apps.scripts. Try adding it something like this:

```
{
  //stuff
  "apps": [
    {
       //Here it is
      "scripts": [
        "ng4-material-dropdown"
      ]
   }
  ],
  //more stuff
}
```

Comment: He uses `Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) `

Comment: Alas, I never used the Angular cli. I double-checked just to make sure, but that file does not exist for me.

Comment: Good call yurzui, do you have a systemjs.config.js Senshi?

Comment: @bgraham That I do!

Comment: That's bad library for systemjs. https://plnkr.co/edit/knwl46BmhplAqDOQcHcf?p=preview It has angular code in umd bundle. That's why we are getting `Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'setGlobalVar'`

Comment: We can use js files like https://plnkr.co/edit/YAYFObkGtmvA1d0Km2bv?p=preview but the library doesn't inline templates so it also won't work

Comment: I would just copy ts sources to project or create correct package

Comment: I'm sorry @yurzui but I don't follow. Please assume I'm a complete Angular noob; I wasn't even aware this file existed until ten minutes ago, let alone that there are replacement options for it or how it relates to loading in components to begin with.

What should I copy over? Just the `dist` folder or the whole thing?

Comment: Copy this folder https://github.com/EricSites/ng4-material-dropdown/tree/master/src/modules

Comment: Alright, I put that folder inside my app folder. It seems to target correctly if I explicitly specify the `ng4-dropdown.module.js` file in my `import` statement, but I then get the following trace: `Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js/animations`